# What are some card in MTG that can change a creature's color?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was creating a deck on deck builder and I wanted to make a [Corrosive Mentor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Corrosive%20Mentor) combination in which I can change a powerful creature's color to black so that it can have the wither effect. Anyone know any cards that can do that? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just go the simpler route and use large black creatures?

Comment: @murgatroid99 Because then he wouldn't be building a Corrosive Mentor combination deck which alters colours to use a wider variety of base creatures!

Comment: If you're looking for advice on building that deck (or any other), you may have some luck putting together what you have on http://tappedout.net and describing how you want the deck to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few cards that can do this. Some specifically turn creatures black:

- **[Darkest Hour](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Darkest%20Hour)**
- **[Grave Servitude](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Grave%20Servitude)**
- **[Sinister Strength](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sinister%20Strength)**

Others let you choose a color, and make creatures that color:

- [**Alchor's Tomb**](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=228270)
- [Blind Seer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blind%20Seer)
- **[Distorting Lens](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Distorting%20Lens)**
- [Illusion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Illusion)
- [**Painter's Servant**](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=146022)
- [Shifting Sky](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shifting%20Sky)
- [Sway of Illusion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sway%20of%20Illusion)
- [Tidal Visionary](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tidal%20Visionary)

And, finally, there are some cards that let you change the word "black" on Corrosive Mentor, so that it affects green creatures instead of black ones, for example:

- [Alter Reality](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Alter%20Reality)
- [Crystal Spray](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Crystal%20Spray)
- [Glamerdye](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Glamerdye)
- [Mind Bend](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mind%20Bend)
- [Sleight of Mind](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sleight%20of%20Mind)
- [Spectral Shift](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spectral%20Shift)
- [Swirl the Mists](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Swirl%20the%20Mists)
- [Trait Doctoring](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Trait%20Doctoring)
- [Whim of Volrath](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Whim%20of%20Volrath)

I've bolded all of the cards that are either black or colorless (so they don't restrict what other cards you can play). Across the last two lists, blue is the most common color, so blue is probably a good second color for this purpose.

Comment: Painter's Servant is colorless. ​ Other than that, all of your answer's non-bold links are to blue cards. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: You're right, Painter's Servant should be bold. I fixed that. And your other statement looks correct to me.